# FORFILES in FOR loops issues

Tags: batch-file

i am trying to make a script to remove empty folders and delete files a number of days old. depending on what the txt file delimiters are set to. I have came up with this so far:

```
::Batch
SET CDID=%~dp0
SET TEST=TRUE

IF %TEST%==TRUE (
    SET COMND1=ECHO
    SET COMND2=ECHO
    ) ELSE (
    SET COMND1=DEL
    SET COMND2=RD
    )
ECHO FILE RAN %date:~10%/%date:~4,2%/%date:~7,2% >>%CDID%\LOG.TXT 
FOR /F "usebackq delims=| tokens=1,2" %%x IN (%CDID%PATH.txt) DO (
    CALL :DEL_FOLDERS "%%x" %%y
    CALL :DEL_FILES "%%x" %%y
    )

GOTO :EOF

:DEL_FILES
    FORFILES /p %1 /s /m *.* /d %2 /c "cmd /c %COMND1% @file"
    GOTO :EOF

:DEL_FOLDERS
    FOR /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir %%1 /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do %COMND2% "%%i" 
    GOTO :EOF


::PATH.txt
C:\Temp\BLANK|10
C:\Temp\New folder|30
```

when i run the script @file will not populate and %%i will not populate, i am not sure what i am doing wrong. Help?

Answer (score 0):

You made a couple of very small errors. In DEL_FOLDERS you used `%%1` which meant that the argument was not expanded (you only needed one % here). You also did not handle the case where there are no files that match or the directories are empty. In the FORFILES command you put `/m *.*`; although the documentation says this is the default, the documentation is incorrect. Missing out the `/m` matches all files (the default) but by saying `/m *.*` you only match files with a dot!

My corrected version is:

```
::Batch
SET CDID=%~dp0
SET TEST=TRUE

IF %TEST%==TRUE (
    SET COMND1=ECHO
    SET COMND2=ECHO
    ) ELSE (
    SET COMND1=DEL
    SET COMND2=RD
    )
ECHO FILE RAN %date:~10%/%date:~4,2%/%date:~7,2% >>%CDID%\LOG.TXT 
FOR /F "usebackq delims=| tokens=1,2" %%x IN (%CDID%PATH.txt) DO (
    CALL :DEL_FOLDERS "%%x" %%y
    CALL :DEL_FILES "%%x" %%y
    )

GOTO :EOF

:DEL_FILES
    FORFILES /p %1 /s /d %2 /c "cmd /c %COMND1% @file" 2> nul
    GOTO :EOF

:DEL_FOLDERS
    FOR /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir "%~1" /s /b /ad 2^>nul ^| sort /r') do %COMND2% "%%i"
    GOTO :EOF


::PATH.txt
C:\Temp\BLANK|10
C:\Temp\New folder|30
```